# error: conflicting types for JNI method

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have this code in java:

```
public native String hello(String inputs, String modems, String outputs);
```

and this code in C:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_hello(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring inputs, jstring modems, jstring outputs)
```

and I have conflicting types error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_hello'
note: previous declaration of 'Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_hello' was here 
make.exe: *** [C:/workspace/marakana//obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ndk_demo/ndk_demo.o] Error 1
```

I tried an example like that and it worked (but with int).
what is the problem?

Comment: You have to show the error you got. And in addition if you changed the signature of the native method, you have to regenerate the header file using `javah` or else your code is inconsistent

Comment: thank u. it's the answer I forgot to build the java file so when I regenerate it, the h file dose not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building `jni` code, you have to ensure that the header file generated using `javah` matches the `native` declarations from the `.class` file.

When you change the native method signature, you have to:

1. Recompile the `.java` file
2. Regenerate the `.h` file from the resulting `.class` file
3. Make sure that the signature of the definition in the `.c` file matches the declaration in the `.h` file

If you miss any of the steps, you can end up being unable to recompile the `.c` file, or end up with a non-functional native library that won't load in the VM.